# 3DS Max 2015 - Viewport issues when using sub-object selection box

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm fairly new to using 3DS Max (2015), and have encountered an issue that I can't figure out.

Whenever I'm using the selection tools (Vertices, Edges, Polys, etc) and drag out a marquee/selection box, it has a regular tendency of either forcing a strange wireframe view, or actually sending the whole viewport grey.

This is immediately fixed once I release the marquee, however it does interfere with my ability to select and manipulate objects, as I'm forced to select by memory. It tends to happen in 'spurts', and then doesn't happen for a few more minutes, so it would seem that it's not a setting issue or the like, as it doesn't happen consistently.

I have discussed the issue with someone who is familiar with the software, and he believes that it is a memory/performance thing, and isn't necessarily a bug. If this is the case, is there any way of disabling the feature?

I have attached images demonstrating the issue below:

1. **Working image.** 
   This is the view for both the images below it; pan or zoom doesn't change at all.
2. **Greyed out viewport.** 
   This is the most common change that happens, and restricts any sort of view of the object (or any other object).
3. **Wireframe**
   This happens reasonably regularly, though not as much as the completely greyed out view. I can handle this view if necessary, though wold still appreciate the ability to disable the 'feature' altogether.

[image: Working 'control' image]
[image: Greyed out viewport]
[image: Wireframe override]

I can confirm that none of the objects are in isolation mode, although it does happen under that mode too (for what it's worth). It also happens in all

My system specs are:

- **Processor**: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4910MQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
- **Graphics**: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 880M - 8GBVRAM
- **RAM**: 32GB
- **OS**: Windows 8.1 x64

I hope that I have provided enough information, and please let me know if you need more.

I tried asking this over on the [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55170/viewport-issues-when-using-marquee-sub-object-selector), but was shot down when finding out that the community seems to have agreed NOT to answer any questions relating to 3D modelling, so I really hope this is a place I can ask! If not, please give me somewhere to go, because I'm running out of options. :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bump... anyone have any ideas?